# JSF mojarra 2.1.7 restoreView isPostBack: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: jsf

I am using PrimeFaces 3.4.2 with Mojarra 2.1.7 on JBoss AS 7.1.1.

I got the following exception when restoring view.

```
21:58:33,203 ERROR  (http--127.0.0.1-8080-7) java.lang.NullPointerException
21:58:36,687 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-7) java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null source
21:58:36,687 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-7)    at java.util.EventObject.<init>(EventObject.java:38)
21:58:36,687 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-7)    at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.<init>(SystemEvent.java:71)
21:58:36,703 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-7)    at javax.faces.event.ComponentSystemEvent.<init>(ComponentSystemEvent.java:73)
21:58:36,703 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-7)    at javax.faces.event.PostRestoreStateEvent.<init>(PostRestoreStateEvent.java:73)
21:58:36,703 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-7)    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.deliverPostRestoreStateEvent(RestoreViewPhase.java:271)
21:58:36,703 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-7)    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:257)
21:58:36,703 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-7)    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
21:58:36,718 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-7)    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:116)
21:58:36,718 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-7)    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
21:58:36,718 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-7)    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
```

```java
@Override
public boolean isPostback() {

    assertNotReleased();
    Boolean postback = (Boolean) this.getAttributes().get(POST_BACK_MARKER);
    if (postback == null) {
        RenderKit rk = this.getRenderKit();
        if (rk != null) {
            postback = rk.getResponseStateManager().isPostback(this);
        } else {
            // ViewRoot hasn't been set yet, so calculate the RK
            ViewHandler vh = this.getApplication().getViewHandler();
            String rkId = vh.calculateRenderKitId(this);
            postback = RenderKitUtils.getResponseStateManager(this, rkId)
                  .isPostback(this);
        }
        this.getAttributes().put(POST_BACK_MARKER, postback);
    }

    return postback;

}

public String calculateRenderKitId(FacesContext context) {

    Util.notNull("context", context);

    Map<String,String> requestParamMap = context.getExternalContext()
        .getRequestParameterMap();
    String result = requestParamMap.get(         // <--------- exception here !!!!!!
        ResponseStateManager.RENDER_KIT_ID_PARAM);

    if (result == null) {
        if (null ==
            (result = context.getApplication().getDefaultRenderKitId())) {
            result = RenderKitFactory.HTML_BASIC_RENDER_KIT;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Exception occurred when `isPostback()` is called, which calls `calculateRenderKitId()`.

```
String result = requestParamMap.get( // <--------- exception here !!!!!!
    ResponseStateManager.RENDER_KIT_ID_PARAM);
```

The `requestParamMap` is not accessable. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Are you invoking this method in a request handled by the Faces Servlet, right?

Comment: @Luiggi: last line of stack trace says `at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)`.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely you run into request parameter limitation. Unfortunately because of exception handling in JSF the real exception is hidden. By default one request can only have 512 parameters, so if you submit large lists, request will trigger uncaught illegalArgumentException-which will be ignored and your request will fail on non-sense nullpointer exceptions.

Try to add this to your jboss standalone.xml

```
 <system-properties>
     <property name="org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.MAX_COUNT" value="5000"/>
</system-properties>
```

Comment: Faced the same issue, setting the property resolved it. Thankx!